# Issue with the long section title

Tags: hyphenation, section-titles

I looked it up, but couldnt find a valid solution so that's why I am asking.
My issue is, I have a long section title that extends over my textwidth as shown in below.
How can I solve this issue? I already set up the margin by using geometry package, and it seems fine except for long section titles.
[image]

Comment: Please make a small, but compilable test document which allows us to reproduce the problem

Comment: BTW: how is this related to the tags you have chosen? Please don't use tags that are not relevant for the question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do please let us know which document class you employ, and which packages (if any) you employ that modify the appearance of sectioning headers.

Comment: Off-topic: Whatever else you end up doing, do be sure to replace "Exteremly" with "Extremely". :-)

Comment: I am sorry, I  am new to this website. I'll try to be more careful about the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Smoothed Peridynamics for the Extremely Large Deformation and Cracking
Problems: Unification of peridynamics and SPH}

SPH is a meshless method, meaning that there is no grid used to approximate a
function value or function derivative at a specific point. In SPH method, domain is
defined with group of particles and desired value of a field is approximated with
the help of interaction between particles. This interaction is achieved by a
smoothing function that determines the weight of neighboring particles of the main
particle. With weighted sum of neighboring particles, the value of a field at main
particle can be approximated. which forms the basis of SPH method.
\end{document}
```

(although the bit sticking out is slightly different with the default margins)

[image]

And here is a simple solution with `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section{Smoothed Peridynamics for the Extremely Large Deformation and Cracking
Problems: Unification of peridynamics and SPH}

SPH is a meshless method, meaning that there is no grid used to approximate a
function value or function derivative at a specific point. In SPH method, domain is
defined with group of particles and desired value of a field is approximated with
the help of interaction between particles. This interaction is achieved by a
smoothing function that determines the weight of neighboring particles of the main
particle. With weighted sum of neighboring particles, the value of a field at main
particle can be approximated. which forms the basis of SPH method.
\end{document}
```

None of the section titles will be fully justified, and they are much less likely to stick out to the right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution.